# Is it possible to set up a Datadog integration to pull events from a rest API endpoint?

Tags: python, api, datadog

I have a rest api endpoint which returns events, in a form of a Json.
Is there a good way to set up a Datadog integration to pull those events into Datadog?

So far I have only come across push solutions using Datadog api.